# Loops x enumeration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am rewriting part of one app of mine, in order to optimize it and make it fast.

As this app was created before blocks, I am now rewriting many stuff to use blocks.

I am replacing loops with enumerate. Do you guys know something if it really worths to convert loops with enumerate? I mean this:

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
  doStuff ([array objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

with this:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    doStuff(obj);
}];
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't strictly necessary, and may actually be more expensive.

Why not just use a `for..in` loop? No need to use a block - reduce complexity wherever you can.

```
for(id obj in array) {
   doStuff(obj);
}
```

Comment: +1 Blocks are nice, but for such simple things the loop is much better suited.